# Is there a T4 template which by-passes the EDMX and goes to the database to generate EF4.1 dbContext classes?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1, t4, edmx

I would dearly love to get rid of the hideous EDMX blob that we are currently wrestling with in our project. Our project is database first, and currently we create the EDMX file using the awful and buggy EDM designer, from whence we generate DbContext and POCO entities using T4 templates.

As the project has matured we find that we have very little difference between our database model and our entity model, essentially a 1-to-1 entity to table mapping which seems to be the mode that EF most prefers. Our only deviation from this is a single use of Table-per-Type inheritance between four of our entities. This in itself has not prooved to be a good design and could well be disgarded.

My question then is - we have no need of the EDMX file, we should be able to drive creation of our DbContext and entity classes directly from the database model, is there a T4 template that can do that?

I have found [this post](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/12/simplifying-entity-framework-data-driven-design/#comment-3529) from Oleg Sych from a couple of years ago which provided T4 templates to accomplish this but the output is for ObjectContext not DbContext. I could of course look to enhance what has been done here, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone already has got this working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) extension to generate POCO models, mapping classes and dbContext from the database.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - I did have a look at the Power Tools, but from what I could make out it's a once only process. I need to remain Database first and each time my database changes update my entity model. This looks to produce a code first solution from an existing database which I would then have to maintain code first going forwards.

Comment: Okay I spent some more time looking at this - and it does work iteratively, I can re-run the reverse engineer each time the DB changes. The only issue now is the UI is cumbersome, Reflecting EFPowerTools.dll reveals that it would be quite straight forward to factor out the Connection string setting code and run the templates, the key function seems to be Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.ReverseEngineerCodeFirst(), although  will ask first if the developers have any plans to provide this type of functionality.